# Releasing Packages for Different OS Flavors

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the process that defines what OSs the build farm builds packages for?

Example: In kinetic, [cartographer is available for Ubuntu Default](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=cartographer) but [cartographer is not available for Debian Jessie](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_dj.html?q=cartographer).

There doesn't seem to be [any magic flags in the rosdistro entry](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/kinetic/distribution.yaml#L903).

Note: cartographer is just an example, I care more about the actual process.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288517/releasing-packages-for-different-os-flavors/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll take a shot at an answer, although I expect @nuclearsandwich will weigh in later.

Blacklisting is done in the `ros_buildfarm_config` repo (`production` branch in this case). Not in the `rosdistro`. For cartographer specifically, see [ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config#110](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/pull/110). Reason given for blacklisting that package on Jessie:

> cartographer's dependency `libceres-dev` doesnt exist on Debian Jessie and we don't plan to backport it as Jessie is almost EOL

The complete blacklist for Jessie is maintained [here](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/blob/e778441a5e2737616d6144260f2cca9ab9de703c/kinetic/release-jessie-build.yaml#L14-L21). See [REP-137: Specification/Release build file](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0137.html#release-build-file) for the spec on the blacklist.

In general Bloom generates release artefacts for all <del>supported</del> *configured* target platforms (generators [here](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/tree/1c1a683184854a64e2777ff9228e7bb89b557eb2/bloom/generators)). As @nuclearsandwich writes:

> The release artifacts bloom generates are determined by the `actions` field of each track in tracks.yaml. If you wish to change what is generated you can modify that list of commands.

Afaik you cannot ask Bloom to not generate for something. Blacklisting is done afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
The release artifacts bloom generates are determined by the `actions` field of each track in tracks.yaml. If you wish to change what is generated you can modify that list of commands. However, if your release repo is public it is nice to generate the info so others can build packages you may not.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
@gvdhoorn covered the salient points excellently. I have very little to add. :)

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-04-13**:
Perfect. Thanks for the thorough answers.